# Start GUI in .profile if it is not running? Linux mint 19

Tags: boot, linux-mint, .profile

I have the following script in my .profile file:

```
systemctl is-active --quiet lightdm && (
    echo Welcome to Terminal) || (
    sleep 8
    startx)
fi
```

the goal is that if the gui is not yet running it will start the GUI. However it never does. It never even says Welcome to Terminal.

**EDIT: I tried using adding a rule to /etc/sudoers but it is not changing the prompt. Here is what I have in the file:**

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification
lukaka  ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service lightdm *
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: *Error:* trailing `fi` without starting `if`. To start `lightdm` : `systemctl start lightdm`. To avoid to run your commands in sub-shell, use `{}` instead of `()`.

Comment: And that will start the GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the end of *`~/.profile`* file:

```
systemctl is-active --quiet lightdm && {
    echo 'Welcome to Terminal'
} || {
  echo 'Starting Desktop GUI in 8 seconds... Press Ctrl-c to abort'
    sleep 8
    sudo systemctl start lightdm
}
```

If your LinuxMint has been set to boot to console instead of desktop then after login to your account you will see message:

> Starting Desktop GUI in 8 seconds... Press Ctrl-c to abort

to interrupt desktop loading, - press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> 
otherwise system will ask you to enter password, if you would pass authorization then desktop GUI would start.

If you already loaded desktop and would start terminal program it will show you welcome message:

> Welcome to Terminal

P.S.

If you don't want to provide `sudo` password for automatic desktop start, do following:

1.
Run `sudo visudo` and provide your password.

2.
If you don't want `sudo` bother you with password everywhere, then
add to the end of file: (substitute your actual user name instead of *YourUserName*)
`YourUserName ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` and save it.
otherwise you can bypass requirement to enter `sudo` password only for starting desktop using following line in `visudo`:
`YourUserName ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service lightdm *`

Comment: This is what I have except it asks for a sudo password, which Id rather not have to type.

Comment: I updated answer, read steps after P.S. to run `sudo` without asking for password

Comment: wont that remove sudo pass prompt for everything?

Comment: How does `lukaka  ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service lightdm *` look?

Comment: Use: `lukaka ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL` then sudo won't bother you with password

Comment: But will it not bother me for a password ever or just with the service because I want sudo to function normally except with this instance.

Comment: I ended up using the command I posted, however like you said I needed to place it  on the bottom line. would you mind changing your answer to have `YourUserName ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service lightdm *` as an alternative so that you only dissable sudo's password prompt for one item?

Comment: Done. Answer updated with your solution.